# I have an insertion problem in my mongo tables and I don't understand what is null

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, rest

I got this error, and i am wondering why ? Do I have to create a specific table or database with mongosh ? Or the functions allow to create rows and tables automatically,
I have the following error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'readPreference')
and it's appear to be on the following

```
const addUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      let user = new User(
        req.body.names,
        req.body.adress,
        req.body.phone
      );
      let result = await client
        .db()
        .collection("users")
        .insertOne(user);
  
      res.status(200).json(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(501).json(error);
    }
  };
```

the User class is the following one

```
class User {
    constructor(names, adress, phone) {
        this.names = names;
        this.adress =  adress;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

and the db function is the following one :

```
function db() {
  var db = new Db(client, "connected");
  return db;
}
```

I tried to change some function parameters, and readed the doc of these function : collection and insertOne

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue when you instantiate new users from the `req.body` when in some cases it could be empty or 'null'

simply checking if it's not null before making new users should fix the issue, given that you provide the name,adress and phone in the request's body.

```
const addUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {

if (req.body) {
      let user = new User(
        req.body.names,
        req.body.adress,
        req.body.phone
      );

      let result = await client
        .db()
        .collection("users")
        .insertOne(user);
  
      res.status(200).json(result);
}
   res.status(200).json([]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(501).json(error);
    }
  }
```